# Kafka on Google Cloud Platform Integration with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, google-cloud-platform

I am running Kafka on GCP and sending message to Topic from Spring Boot App.
In GCP consumer window, messages are not getting displayed.

I have allowed all firewall access to my VM which is running Kafka.

Any thoughts??

Exception in spring IDE console

```
2018-10-10 00:25:06.819  INFO 4472 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 1.0.2
2018-10-10 00:25:06.820  INFO 4472 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : 
2a121f7b1d402825
2018-10-10 00:25:38.158 ERROR 4472 --- [ad | producer-1] 
o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when 
sending a message with key='null' and payload='888' to topic test:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) 
for test-0: 30034 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time .
```

Comment: Can you show your server properties? Can you try using the Kafka CLI tools before trying Spring boot?

Comment: Its working with cli tools on gcp - i opened two windows 1 for producer and 1 for consumer. Messages were received successfully

Comment: And you're running the Spring app on the same machines that those terminal sessions are logged into?

Comment: no it is on my local but i am giving the **spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers ** address in my local app. The address will be the external ip provided by the VM instance.

Comment: You should try those two terminal sessions outside of GCP, where the app will run, then. That port connection might be enough for the first hop to Kafka, but it's not enough to connect to the remainder of the brokers. See the AWS section of this post, which also applies to GCP https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/